# Get the value of Editable Text from Page using Macro in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I am using the cms repeater control to pull the data from custom table.
The repeater hast to pull the data based on the value entered in Editable Text field of the same page.

Because Editable text box has the feature of inherit if empty for their child. So its easy to put the specific value in parent alone is enough.

I saw few thing on documentation nothing seems to be working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
{% CurrentDocument.DocumentContent["editabletext"] #%}
```

where editabletext is codename of your web part.

Comment: I set the editable text to inherit if empty but this macro didn't return the value in child page. Is there any other way to get this.

Comment: You may try {% CurrentPageInfo.DocumentContent["editabletext"] #%} but if this doesn't work I don't think anything else will.

Comment: Since K# macro engine supports loops I suggest using loop to traverse through parent documents to find your value. (CurrentDocument.Parent.Parent...)